# Spring Test : can't insert a hexadecimal value into a hsqldb from import.sql file

Tags: hsqldb, spring-test

I'm performing JUnit tests with spring and hibernate. It works fine when I use a MySql database on my PC.
In order to launch this tests on any environment I've set a virtual database: hsqldb. And I insert the data from the import.sql file.
Here my configuration:

```
enter code here
```

and persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider" />
    </properties>
```

So, when I launch test class the data (in the import.sql file) are inserted in the database and the tests runs.
My problem is that I have some hexadecimal values that are not inserted in database and I don't know why. Here an example of hexadecimal data in import.sql:

```
INSERT INTO rejeu_commande_xml (order_id, compressed_request) VALUES (10000108000000001, 0x777d010078daed5ddd72e336967e15962f2649cdb8c57f8a1e4513b57e1cd54896cb523b99dca8281292b14d910a49b9edbdda9ad9a7d8abad5c6db6e6729f60f2267992054052a2fe2c9222a91fa32fda220102e4013ee07c07070795bfbc4c4de619382eb4ad6fafb80fec15032cdd36a035f9f6ead3a0755dbe625c4fb30ccdb42df0edd52b70affe52ad582e7fa33b40f3407dee7af614383dc7000e834ab3dc6faf9e3c6f76532a7df9f2e583ed68d6047cd0ed694977a6577e8e1bf4fc1bb94a8ffc55b5a26b1eaa74f200c6c001960735b3dda8f67bad41a5b435a9025e3ce058e4b720b4af454d1a09222b5e6bec98bd1601e0ae476259be56479a2e0a92381ae94aa51479a8a2cf1d549cfe5ab70d506d7e7a401545ef54c817234135d077577996e3af59fe9ae706ac74c3cb3792fc4151843fb2dc0dcba227a3792b0698);
```

This data are defined as LONGBLOB in my MySql database and I think this type isn't supported by HSQLDB.

How could I insert this data in order to get it from my test class?

thank you very much in advance!
Aurea

Answer (score 3):

The format of the hexadecimal value for HSQLDB requires single quotes around the hex string. Both examples below should work.

```
INSERT INTO rejeu_commande_xml (order_id, compressed_request) VALUES (10000108000000001, x'777d010078da')
INSERT INTO rejeu_commande_xml (order_id, compressed_request) VALUES (10000108000000001, '777d010078da')
```

Hibernate should use LONGVARBINARY, VARBINARY or BLOB for the HSQLDB datatype, instead of LONGBLOB.